# FTP transfer only new files

Tags: ftp, jenkins, maven-3, sftp, jenkins-plugins

I'm using maven+jenkis on my web project. With jenkis I upload WEB-INF folder on my server. Now I want to transfer only the most recent files. Do I set some propertis on my ftp config file, or I'll execute a particular script for jenkis?

Answer (score 0):

I would use rsync. It transfers only the necessary files and I think it can only send only changed parts of large files.